# Addition of Some Image Next to "Add to Cart" Button

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I need an image to be appeared next to Add to Cart button in WooCommerce product page, using Advanced Custom Fields plugin. In order to displaying values, as I know, **the_field** function must be added to some page template. In Which template file and where should I place the **the_field** function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what type of "add to cart" you are using (simple product, variable, etc).

Regardless, each are in this directory (for single-product): `templates/single-product/add-to-cart`.

You should (for best results) use the image array for your ACF content.

You would write this (changing the `get_field('image')` to `get_field('your_field_name')`:

```
<?php 

$image = get_field('image'); // assigns the image field to the variable of $image

if( !empty($image) ): ?> <!--if the $image variable isn't empty, display the following:-->

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" /> <!--displays the URL for the image variable and also the alt tag which is entered in the WordPress media library-->

<?php endif; ?> <!--ends the if statement -->
```

If you wanted a basic display, you could use image URL and do this:

```
<?php if( get_field('image') ): ?> <!--only shows the image field if it exists (an image was uploaded through ACF)-->

    <img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" /> <!--displays the URL of the image if it is not an array/ID set in ACF field parameters, but a URL -->

<?php endif; ?> <!-- end the IF statement -->
```

I prefer using the alt tag when at all possible.

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I was looking for. My php is poor, can you give me a source explaining the code you wrote above so I can edit it?

Comment: I'll add comments to what is above. It is from ACF, but they expect you to know PHP.